# Unity Player in 2D platform game run very slow on iOS

Tags: ios, performance, unity-game-engine, 2d, platform

Sorry about My English. 
I developed 2D Platform  game using Unity and its work perfect on Android and I publish it. 
when I switched platform to iOS and test it on device the player run very very VERY SLOW when it on platform, but when player jump and try to move left and right while jumping its perfect move.

Help Please

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well, this is a side scroll game ?
And the 'slowness' problem happen only when you move on the ground ?

What do you use for the movement, a RigidBody2D ?
In that case perhaps you should look the settings of physics frictions.

Say me if that help

Comment: yesr i used RigidBody2D     this is screenshot of game  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wDlPxUiHp8DZhkYmcaQG_7iW7rFZQq8RF9jaQ1n1h9pbhLGBWXC3_9SysLBCuNKVw9rs=h900-rw

Comment: What do you use for the movement, and collision, a Rigidbody2D ?
In that case perhaps you should look the settings of physics frictions. (Edit>ProjectSettings>Physics2D)
Perhaps in the iOs compilation the "value" of the frictions change and this is why the player is so slow.

Comment: thanks man for reply .. the solution was increased speed value  .. thanks again